# Multi server administration - Failed to import Maintenance Plan to named instance

Tags: sql-server, maintenance-plans, multi-server-admin

I have a multi server administration environment and several maintenance plans deployed already. My MSX server is SQL2014. The problem i'm having is deploying maintenance plans to a 2008R2 named instance which is running alongside a default 2014 instance (which is working with MSX MPs already).

I'm getting this error:

```
[000] Failed to import Maintenance Plan 'MSA backup' from MSX: Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DtsRuntimeException: Error loading from XML. No further detailed error information can be specified for this problem because no Events object was passed where detailed error information can be stored.
 ---> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0xC0011008): Error loading from XML. No further detailed error information can be specified for this problem because no Events object was passed where detailed error information can be stored.
```

I added the account under which the agent service is running on the MSX to the sysadmin role on the named instance.

I know it's trying to import to SSIS but there can only be one SSIS instance on a machine and that is the default, 2014 instance.

Locally created MPs run without problems. I can provide more info if needed.

I have googled without luck so far, but will continue.

TY.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that the Maintenance Plans are really just SSIS Packages under the hood. As your MSX server is 2014, I'm assuming that is where you created them, which means the SSIS package version will be 2014. You will most likely have to downgrade your packages to have them run on SQL 2008 R2, which means you won't be able to include them in your master job server.

This [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/agent/create-a-multiserver-environment?view=sql-server-2017) states that SSIS only supports target servers that are the same version or higher than the master server version, so your 2008 R2 server would either have to be the master or you need to revert to using T-SQL based maintenance jobs instead of Maintenance Plans.

Comment: I guess you are right. Back to the drawing it seems. Ty.